# Inserting Dates Using Paragraph Style

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, data-merge

[image: Project Screenshot]

Hello, so I’m making a planner and I want to add dynamic dates, so what I did is customizing a paragraph style with a numbering list, it works fine until I start the second column, apparently, it's giving the priority to the first page (the right one), and I want it to continue across the spread, is it possible to do that in paragraph style? Or in any other way? I tried data merge, but it doesn’t seem suitable to my kind of planner nor does the text variables.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How would anything dynamic work since you'd need 31, 30, 28 (possibly 29) dates each month? And the position of #1 would change every month.

Comment: I don't think that you can do it they way you are attempting.  you can however do a data merge with the correct spreadsheet.  I do a lot of calendars and I set this up a few years ago.  I can set you up with the excel file and instructions for how to update it if you are interested.  The setup that I have merges the entire month per record with extra fields for the little previous and future month calendars.  All you have to do is set up a single month layout and merge to a document.  There might be small tweaks needed after that, but pretty quick.  Better than typing the whole thing.

Comment: @Alith7 that would be great! I tried data merge but it didn't work for me, I had days of the weeks as columns and the dates that fall in with the same days under it, but that doesn't seem to work because I need all of the 4-5 weeks in one spread. also, I have to have two types of calendar system both gregorian calendar & Islamic Calendar, that's why I'm a little skeptical about how can data merge work in my case, but any help is most welcomed, thank you.

Comment: @Scott I have each month in a seprate file so thats okay in my case.

Comment: I can't see how numbered list is helpful here. It's just 30 numbers, takes no time to write manually. It looks like you have a table? I might instead use separate frames for each day linked together in the right order. If you need to move #1 from Monday to Friday you just delete the first 4 frames. (Beware that there are months with 6 weeks (as in your screenshot), not just 5 (as in your comment).)

Comment: @Wolff I have multiple files to be adjusted 12 months for each calendar, also I'm using a two-calendar system (gregorian and Islamic) I don't need to change the layout I only need a way of inserting dates automatically because that amount of data if inserted manually could have some flaws.

Comment: @fatenjamal I will pull together the files today.  To be clear though, you are looking for the dates to flow in a Monday-Sunday type columns, correct? Or do you always want it to start with 1 in the upper right corner box?

Comment: @Alith Can you provide me with a way of contact? I tried to reach you via twitter because I didn't find an email on your profile, many many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can do it they way you are attempting.  you can however do a data merge with the correct spreadsheet.  I do a lot of calendars and I set this up a few years ago.  I can set you up with the excel file and instructions for how to update it if you are interested.  The setup that I have merges the entire month per record with extra fields for the little calendars and other extras.

[image: calendar merge example]

It is slightly tedious to set up the original excel and data merge, but once it's established, it's VERY easy to update for future versions.  Doing a couple find/replace updates the year and for the Gregorian calendar (with the exception of leap year) the days only shift forward one day Monday -> Tuesday every year so you can grab the whole block and shift it over, and the weeks that go back to "1" you just shift those.

For the little bit of adjustment to the sheet every year, it guarantees that you won't have any days entered wrong.

Couple other important things, set up all your pieces for the main calendar as separate text boxes for each day, add how you are going to add in the 6th week row, and then after you do the data merge you can just delete from the months that don't have it.  If you are doing the little calendars, set them up as a paragraph block with tabs, if you set up the block and tabs correctly, you don't have to figure in any carriage returns.  Finally, use character and paragraph styles, it makes changing things after your merge so much easier.

[image: Merge View of Layout]

[image: Merge Preview]

Comment: Alith7, Hello, would you be so kind as to share the excel sheet of the calendar assembly? thanks a lot